# apache user cannot sudo while running via httpd

Tags: linux, sudo, apache-httpd

I have a requirement where an web application (php) must run a script on another server. I tested running the remote script as apache user by sudo-ing to the apache user via the root user. The script on the remote machine was executed properly. However when I run it via the php script ran by a request from the web browser, it does not run properly. Any ideas how to work around this one?

1. Login via root
2. Change the sesu access of apache

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/visudo

   Cmnd_Alias WEBREMOTE = /usr/bin/ssh, /var/www/html/test_shell.sh

   apache   ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:WEBREMOTE
   ```
3. Sudo to the apache user

   ```
   sudo -u apache -s
   ```
4. Run the script remotely

   ```
   sudo -S ssh their.user@remote.machine 'bash -s' < /var/www/html/test_shell.sh test_param & > /dev/null
   ```
5. The shell script can run properly by checking the log from the
   remote.machine
6. When you try to run the same script via php's exec, the code does
   not run

   ```
    <?php
    $shellcmd = "sudo -S ssh their.user@remote.machine 'bash -s' < /var/www/html/test_shell.sh $test_param & > /dev/null";
    $ret = exec($shellcmd);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "shellcmd result: [$ret]";

    $ret2=shell_exec($shellcmd);
    echo "<br />";
    echo "shellcmd result: [$ret2]";
    ?>
   ```

The resulting php just returns a blank result either via exec or exec_shell, also the log inside the test_shell.sh does not run in the remote machine. The php page also does not result in an error, did I miss any settings here?

Comment: All I will say is that this is a very bad idea. It is never a good idea to give php access to run a script on webserver, let alone give it SUDO permissions.

Comment: Why do you need to `sudo` at all? Why not just let `ssh` run under the web server user ID?

Comment: @Celada I am not sure what do you mean by web server user ID, wwwUser? In my system the running user is apache. Is there another user?

Comment: @DevNull yes, I know that giving the web script an access right is not a good idea, but I plan to limit it to just the script and the ssh app.

Comment: @Nap doesn't matter what the user it. For example on Debian/Ubuntu systems by default it is `www-data`. My point is that that user can run `ssh` just as easily as any other user. I was wondering why you would need to `sudo` to another user (indeed `sudo` to root?) just to run ssh?

Comment: @Nap, you won't be able to limit it enough because a malicious person would need to exploit one vulnerability to change the contents of the `.sh` file and now you gave them the ability to execute a `.sh` script on the system with SUDO permissions, essentially allowing them to execute anything they want. I just want you to be aware of that.

Comment: @Celada The reason for using Sudo is to avoid the prompting of password of the apache user. The apache user has no user folder where the .ssh can share the id_sa.pub to the remote authorized_list. I am not sure for other linux version, probably it is just Redhat/Centos version that uses web user with no user folder.

Comment: @DevNull yeah, I know this is a bad idea. But the system is for a back office application which only reside in the intranet under a fire wall. of course a malicious user can also be an insider of the company. Anyway, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Nap if the apache user has no home directory in which to put the `id_rsa` file then you should simply put the file elsewhere and point to it with `ssh`'s `-i` option.